# IAP How to check if user has already trialled (at any time in the past)?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I'm implementing auto-renewable subscriptions with trial on my iOS app, and I need to disclose, at our checkout screen, the limit date when the user can disable the auto-renewal in order not to be charged.

> **You clearly and conspicuously disclose to users the following information regarding Your auto-renewing subscription:**
>   - Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period

This means that if I provide a 7-day trial, I must add a label stating that the user can disable it until (today + 7 days).

However, there will be the case where the user has already trialled, subscribed and cancelled the subscription, and now wants to subscribe once again. This time, they won't be able to have another trial period.

As there is no trial, there is no need to add that label I mentioned earlier.

How can I check whether the user has trialled or not in the past and display the correct information accordingly?

Answer (score 5):

> If a previous subscription period in the receipt has the value `true`
>   for either the `is_trial_period` or the `is_in_intro_offer_period` key,
>   the user is not eligible for a free trial or introductory price within
>   that subscription group.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html